# PyDev does not show up in Window > Preferences for Eclipse 4.7 (Oxygen)

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I have Java 1.8 and Eclipse 4.7.0 (Oxygen), and I tried installing PyDev thru "Eclipse Marketplace" and "Install New Software" but no matter what I do, PyDev never shows up under Window > Preferences.  So it looks like there has been a regression.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce that here (so, it definitely works), my guess is that it's some issue in your configuration... if you're in Linux, it's possible that you have the IDE installed as root and are trying to add plugins as another user? Also, make sure it's java 8 and not java 9 and double check if org.python.pydev was actually downloaded and is in your eclipse/plugins and you have permissions in that folder.

An easy workaround would be using LiClipse (http://www.liclipse.com), which provides an Eclipse bundled with PyDev which has everything pre-configured (although it's commercial).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (on Windows 10, Eclipse Oxygen, Java 8, PyDev 6.1).  It turned out to be a permissions issue.  When I initially installed Eclipse, I ran the installer as an Administrator so that I could install it in `C:\Program Files\eclipse.oxygen`.  However, even when running Eclipse as an Administrator, that still didn't resolve the PyDev installation issue.

In the end, I resolved it by uninstalling Eclipse and reinstalling it in an unprivileged location.